# How to Embed thumbnails in images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of 200X120 thumbnails and a bunch of high quality images, Apparently when I just resize the thumbnails with img size the quality suffers, so we are loading two images from the server the image thumbnail and the actual, I am just trying to optimize my site for speed a little saw someone mention embedding thumbs in the image, does anyone know a program that does that? Is this the best way to achieve my goal of high quality thumbnails?

Comment: Can't understand what is embedding thumb "in" image. You mean you are showing the thumbnail and in some way, the user interest in that image and show the high res version?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a problem only in IE6 and IE7? Modern browsers use bicubic resampling, so you should be able to resize at the  level with no consequences. If using IE6 or IE7, check [this blog entry](http://www.aaronwpearson.com/image-resizing-in-internet-explorer-7/) for a decent solution.

Basically, it involves using the style

```
img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
```

in those MS browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can embed a thumbnail into the image file. Similar things are available for other media, such as MP3 files, where you can attach an image for the album cover, etc. Even if you could, there are no functions you can use to differ between the actual image and the thumbnail image.

Also, do not resize large HD images into thumbnails within the HTML. The client still has to download the *entire* file even to resize it. If there is a grid of 9 images, that's 9 very large HD images they have to download when they could have downloaded smaller thumbnails of those images instead.

Answer (score 0):

Google "Exif".  There's hundreds of applications that read/write exif attributes, including ones that I'm sure embed and extract the thumbnail image attribute.  Or you can roll your own with I'm sure just about any language and the right plugin.

When you're serving thumbnails, you may opt to instead programmatically extract this thumbnail attribute from the image and serve that, rather than the whole image file shrunk after delivery using html styling.